# CreatingJupyter Notebook Failed: error to write a readonly database

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I have installed Jupyter notebook.
with python 3

When I try to create a new notebook file, I get a pop up windows saying:
[Pop up error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8uBiq.png)
An error occurred while creating a new notebook.
Unexpected error while saving file: Untitled.ipynb attempt to write a readonly database

From the terminal:

```
[W 20:00:11.307 NotebookApp] 500 POST /api/contents (127.0.0.1): Unexpected error while saving file: Untitled.ipynb attempt to write a readonly database         
[W 20:00:11.307 NotebookApp] Unexpected error while saving file: Untitled.ipynb attempt to write a readonly database
```

Comment: quick addition: I am using Ubuntu 18.04, Only way to work is to access `sudo bash` first and then type:  `jupyter notebook --allow-root` to use Jupyter Notebook without any problem.
I can't just type `$ jupyter notebook`

Comment: Looks like I found a solution. `sudo chown -R tarik-deeplearning:tarik-deeplearning /home/tarik-deeplearning/.local/share/jupyter` to change permission. then need to repeat that process (check ownership and fix it) until you can save again. `sudo chown -R tarik-deeplearning:tarik-deeplearning /home/tarik-deeplearning/Projects/GoogleNet/.ipynb_checkpoints` & it works.